# Do gravitational waves produce real accelerations?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-electrodynamics, gravitational-waves

Do gravitational waves produce real accelerations? For example, if I have an electron and a gravitational wave passes by, will the electron emit electromagnetic waves according for instance to Larmor formula?

Comment: See e.g. "The Emission of Electromagnetic Radiation from Charges Accelerated by Gravitational Waves and its Astrophysical Implications" by Mitchell Revalski, Will Rhodes, Thulsi Wickramasinghe. It's available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00893